# Sync Windows 7 taskbar across machines

Tags: windows-7, sync, taskbar

I want all my Windows 7 machines to have the same exact items **pinned** in my taskbar / superbar, including any custom jumplist shortcuts.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

No, unfortunately Microsoft specifically prevents programs (and by extension, you unless you're manipulating the UI manually) from modifying your taskbar in Windows 7. When developing Windows 7, they wanted to avoid the overload of every program trying to add itself to Quick Launch.

Comment: Um, there's no quick launch as such in windows 7. Perhaps you're referring to the ability to pin items to the taskbar?

Comment: The answer is correct whether referring to Quick Launch or the new pinable Taskbar. In fact the new Taskbar is even more protected and the API's are completely closed to avoid application adding themselves to the Taskbar.

Comment: @RCIX: When I mentioned Quick Launch, I was referring to earlier versions of Windows where every program could simply drop a shortcut into the Quick Launch folder and in no time flat, you'd have a ton of shortcuts you didn't ask for.

Comment: I just find it very handy. I don't use desktop shortcuts, i use "QuickLaunch" buttons instead. But now i need to add them manually (although, starting application, rightclick->pin to taskbar)

Comment: I'm referring to the application shortcuts and what you have pinned, not the notifications area

Comment: I'm not talking about the notification area either. Microsoft has ensured that the pinned entries cannot be changed by a program.

Comment: Although, I think the notification area is the same.

Answer (score -1):

The pinned icons are really just shortcuts (.lnk) files just like quick launch, so you just have to copy the right .lnk files into the right folder to have them show up.  I don't know about syncing jump lists, I presume those are in the registry.

```
 C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Microsoft blocks automated changes to the taskbar, so copying a shortcut in there doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose I should have actually tested it first.  I had noted the existence for the shortcuts.  That explains issues when a program is reinstalled: the taskbar icon goes to a white page and has to be re-pinned.